# Get current time and deal with daylight saving time for a particular timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having trouble of using datetime in SQL Server 2012, my SQL database is hosted on a server that is using different timezone than the timezone I would like to use for my application, also my timezone I want to use is under daylight saving time, so I have to change the code every time this (daylight saving time) happens

So if I use:

```
SELECT Getdate()
```

I will get current date and time of the server (wherever your database is hosted from), the result will be something like :

> 2015-12-23 09:09:40.303

Is there anyway or a built-in method in SQL that I can use to retrieve current date and time of particular timezone that also observes daylight saving time, or specifically in this case it is **Central Standard Time** (for USA), I would like it to take care of the daylight saving time automatically instead of having to manually modify the code every time the daylight saving time occurs.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to store all your data in UTC, and use GetUtcDate() ?

Comment: Why particularly you want this in sql /database end.easily achievable from c# code.In .net 3.5 there is a class called `TimeZoneInfo`.So idea is getting UTC and adjust the offset like `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
    DateTime.UtcNow, "Central Standard Time");`

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement

Comment: Use your application code to generate the necessary dates and times and send them to your db as parameters when required.

Answer (score 1):

Ok reiterating my comments again I would say that you can get UTC time first then get the actual time information for zone.

So something like this could server the purpose-

```
TimeZoneInfo centralUSAZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");

DateTime centralUSATime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, centralUSAZone);
```

`ConvertTimeFromUtc` Function essentially takes two parameters.

> dateTime
>      Type: System.DateTime
>
> **The Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).**
>
> destinationTimeZone
>       Type: System.TimeZoneInfo
>
> **The time zone to convert dateTime to.**

Have a detailed look on msdn doc.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but I think I've asked this question before for the C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657578 , so basically I can retrieve the current time and assign it to a variable on C# without any problem but I am having trouble to pass it to SQL query, I may have to ask another question, in the meantime this question is looking for a solution in SQL.

Comment: Then edit this question more and tell us actual problem you are facing.

Comment: I think I will create another question for that, I will leave this question as-is to find a solution in SQL that doesn't need to use .NET resources, someone else may use PHP or other language and want to know, right.

Answer (score 0):

You can offset from one timezone to another using [SWITCHOFFSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb677244(v=sql.110).aspx).  But the second parameter requires you to adjust for daylight savings.

From MSDN:

> time_zone Is a character string in the format [+|-]TZH:TZM or a signed
>   integer (of minutes) that represents the time zone offset, and is
>   assumed to be daylight-saving aware and adjusted.

There is a discussion on [Stack DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28187/how-can-i-get-the-correct-offset-between-utc-and-local-times-for-a-date-that-is) that might help you.  TL/DR: Using the CLR was the most popular answer.

Non-Daylight Saving Example:

```
SELECT
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()                                AS Server_Date_Time_WithTZone,
    SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+04:00')        AS NewTZone
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, timezones can get really hard in the US because of Daylight Savings Time. You should probably use a library or CLR function, but if you cannot, here is a naive SQL-only implementation. It's naive because:

1. It assumes US only rules (DST is 2AM on some pre-defined Sunday, etc).
2. It assumes you don't have dates prior to 1970
3. It assumes you know the local timezone offsets (i.e.: EST=-05:00, EDT=-04:00, etc.)

Here's the SQL:

```
-- make a table (#dst) of years 1970-2101. Note that DST could change in the future and
-- everything was all custom and jacked before 1970 in the US.
declare @first_year varchar(4) = '1970'
declare @last_year varchar(4) = '2101'

-- make a table of all the years desired
if object_id('tempdb..#years') is not null drop table #years
;with cte as (
    select cast(@first_year as int) as int_year
          ,@first_year as str_year
          ,cast(@first_year + '-01-01' as datetime) as start_of_year
    union all
    select int_year + 1
          ,cast(int_year + 1 as varchar(4))
          ,dateadd(year, 1, start_of_year)
    from cte
    where int_year + 1 <= @last_year
)
select *
into #years
from cte
option (maxrecursion 500);

-- make a staging table of all the important DST dates each year
if object_id('tempdb..#dst_stage') is not null drop table #dst_stage
select dst_date
      ,time_period
      ,int_year
      ,row_number() over (order by dst_date) as ordinal
into #dst_stage
from (
    -- start of year
    select y.start_of_year as dst_date
          ,'start of year' as time_period
          ,int_year
    from #years y

    union all
    select dateadd(year, 1, y.start_of_year)
          ,'start of year' as time_period
          ,int_year
    from #years y
    where y.str_year = @last_year

    -- start of dst
    union all
    select
        case
            when y.int_year >= 2007 then
                -- second sunday in march
                dateadd(day, ((7 - datepart(weekday, y.str_year + '-03-08')) + 1) % 7, y.str_year + '-03-08')
            when y.int_year between 1987 and 2006 then
                -- first sunday in april
                dateadd(day, ((7 - datepart(weekday, y.str_year + '-04-01')) + 1) % 7, y.str_year + '-04-01')
            when y.int_year = 1974 then
                -- special case
                cast('1974-01-06' as datetime)
            when y.int_year = 1975 then
                -- special case
                cast('1975-02-23' as datetime)
            else
                -- last sunday in april
                dateadd(day, ((7 - datepart(weekday, y.str_year + '-04-24')) + 1) % 7, y.str_year + '-04-24')
        end
        ,'start of dst' as time_period
        ,int_year
    from #years y

    -- end of dst
    union all
    select
        case
            when y.int_year >= 2007 then
                -- first sunday in november
                dateadd(day, ((7 - datepart(weekday, y.str_year + '-11-01')) + 1) % 7, y.str_year + '-11-01')
            else
                -- last sunday in october
                dateadd(day, ((7 - datepart(weekday, y.str_year + '-10-25')) + 1) % 7, y.str_year + '-10-25')
        end
        ,'end of dst' as time_period
        ,int_year
    from #years y
) y
order by 1

-- assemble a final table
if object_id('tempdb..#dst') is not null drop table #dst
select a.dst_date +
          case
             when a.time_period = 'start of dst' then ' 03:00'
             when a.time_period = 'end of dst' then ' 02:00'
             else ' 00:00'
          end as start_date
      ,b.dst_date +
          case
             when b.time_period = 'start of dst' then ' 02:00'
             when b.time_period = 'end of dst' then ' 01:00'
             else ' 00:00'
          end as end_date
      ,cast(case when a.time_period = 'start of dst' then 1 else 0 end as bit) as is_dst
      ,cast(0 as bit) as is_ambiguous
      ,cast(0 as bit) as is_invalid
into #dst
from #dst_stage a
join #dst_stage b on a.ordinal + 1 = b.ordinal
union all
select a.dst_date + ' 02:00' as start_date
      ,a.dst_date + ' 03:00' as end_date
      ,cast(1 as bit) as is_dst
      ,cast(0 as bit) as is_ambiguous
      ,cast(1 as bit) as is_invalid
from #dst_stage a
where a.time_period = 'start of dst'
union all
select a.dst_date + ' 01:00' as start_date
      ,a.dst_date + ' 02:00' as end_date
      ,cast(0 as bit) as is_dst
      ,cast(1 as bit) as is_ambiguous
      ,cast(0 as bit) as is_invalid
from #dst_stage a
where a.time_period = 'end of dst'
order by 1

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Test Eastern
select
    the_date as eastern_local
    ,todatetimeoffset(the_date, case when b.is_dst = 1 then '-04:00' else '-05:00' end) as eastern_local_tz
    ,switchoffset(todatetimeoffset(the_date, case when b.is_dst = 1 then '-04:00' else '-05:00' end), '+00:00') as utc_tz
    --,b.*
from (
    select cast('2015-03-08' as datetime) as the_date
    union all select cast('2015-03-08 02:30' as datetime) as the_date
    union all select cast('2015-03-08 13:00' as datetime) as the_date
    union all select cast('2015-11-01 01:30' as datetime) as the_date
    union all select cast('2015-11-01 03:00' as datetime) as the_date
) a left join
#dst b on b.start_date <= a.the_date and a.the_date < b.end_date
```